# FileInfo.GetFiles() and special characters (accents)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When I insert in DB a string that contains special character as a "à" or a "é" from a FileInfo.GetFiles() item, I get issues and SQL save splitted special char. Non-special chars are OK.

For instance, "à" becomes "a`", and "é" becomes "e´". Did anyone get this kind of trouble?

Here is the code

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
{
 Logger.LogInfo("Info: " + fi.Name);
}
```

Basically, if string is "sàrl", log saved "Info: sa`rl"

When I breakpoint trough VS, I see the string with "à" but when I log it, char are splitted.

My SQL collation is Latin CI AS (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) and DB already host string with special char without problem.

Thanks folks

**EDIT**

I have trouble when I insert the fi.Name into the final table too:

```
public bool InsertFile(string fileName, Societe company, string remark, PersonnelAM creator)
        {
            string commandText = (@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TB_DOCSOCIETE_COM] " +
                                    "([IdtSOC] " +
                                    ",[NomDOC] " +
                                   ",[RemDOC] " +
                                   ",[DateDOC] " +
                                   ",[IdtPER]) " +
                                    "VALUES " +
                                   "(@company" +
                                   ",@fileName" +
                                   ",@remark" +
                                   ",@date" +
                                   ",@creator) SELECT @@IDENTITY");

            var identity = CreateCommand(commandText,
                    new SqlParameter("@fileName", DAOHelper.HandleNullValueAndMinDateTime<string>(fileName)),
                    new SqlParameter("@company", DAOHelper.HandleNullValueAndMinDateTime<int>(company.Id)),
                    new SqlParameter("@remark", DAOHelper.HandleNullValueAndMinDateTime<string>(remark)),
                    new SqlParameter("@date", DAOHelper.HandleNullValueAndMinDateTime<DateTime>(DateTime.Now)),
                    new SqlParameter("@creator", DAOHelper.HandleNullValueAndMinDateTime<int>(creator.id))
                     ).ExecuteScalar();

            return int.Parse(identity.ToString()) > 0;
        }
```

I'm using NLog so data is varchar(8000) for message column and code that logs message is

```
public static bool LogInfo(Exception ex, string message = "")
        {
            try
            {
                GetLogger().Log(LogLevel.Info, ex, message);
            }
            #pragma warning disable 0168
            catch (Exception exception)
            #pragma warning restore 0168
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

**EDIT 2 :**

To be clear about DB, those 3 lines:

```
Logger.LogInfo("BL1 " + "sàrl is right saved");
Logger.LogInfo("BL2 " + fi.Name + " is not right saved");
Logger.LogInfo("BL3 " + "sàrl" + " - " + fi.Name + " is not right too!");
```

Gave me that result in DB:

```
BL1 sàrl is right saved
BL2 ENTERPRISE Sa`rl - file.pdf is not right saved
BL3 sàrl - ENTERPRISE Sa`rl - file.pdf is not right too!
```

So it doesn't come from DB, it is an issue about the string (encoding?)

Comment: Show your log code or tell us which library you use for logging. It looks like it saves Unicode characters in decomposed form.

Comment: What is the type of the column where you are storing this, `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: @HansKesting varchar(8000)

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm using NLog but issue is coming even if I made a INSERT with SQL parameter

Comment: @CodeCaster please see my second edit, it should help :-)

Comment: @clement if you put a breakpoint on AMLogger.LoggerAM.LogInfo("BL2 "... what is the fi.name variable value?

Comment: @Giox it is right encoded: sàrl. Visual Studio give a representation of the string so I didn't trust VS in that kind of situation :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varchar(8000)`

Make the column `NVARCHAR`. This is not a collation issue. Collations determine the sort order and comparison rules, not the storage. Is true that for non-unicode columns (`varchar`) the collation is used as hint to determine the code page of the result. But code page will only get you so far, as obviously a 1 byte encoding code page cannot match the entire space of the file system naming, which is 2 bytes encoding Unicode based.

Use an Unicode column: `NVARCHAR`.

If you want to understand what are you experiencing, just run this:

```
declare @a nvarchar(4000) = NCHAR(0x00E0) +  N'a' + NCHAR(0x0300)
select @a, cast(@a as varchar);
```

Unicode is full of wonderful surprises, like [Combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). You can't distinguish them visually, but they sure show up when you look at the actual encoded bytes.

Comment: Could you explain more? If I give to the logger a C# string that is "à"+file.Name, "à" is saved correctly in DB but file.Name is broken, so VARCHAR is saving the first "à". CARCHAR can save the first "à" so why don't he save the second one in file.Name?

Comment: I already explained everything, including all symptoms and problems you describe. Look at the **exact** Unicode codes for the characters you're testing (eg. use `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` and then display the bytes).

Comment: OK sorry I trough it was a website to help people

Comment: Did you do what I asked? Look at the exact Unicode codes for the characters you're testing ... Don't be [this guy](http://www.skidmore.edu/~pdwyer/e/eoc/help_vampire.htm).

Comment: I've read your edit it is very clearier than your previous answer. I'm not vampire but if I didn't understand, some other people won't understand too. I just wanted explanations because the fix you gave looked too magic for scientific/rationel people like me... SO I would thank you for the answer and it fix the issue!